# what's the best lubricant for door locks?

Tags: locks, key, door, lubrication, power-door-lock

I'm looking into door lock lubrication and protection. I'm having a hard time deciding between what to use.

I watched a few videos on this.

A professional locksmith used dry ptfe lubricant spray after cleaning the lock with brake clean and then sprayed white lithium grease to "protect the lock"
but after watching how lithium grease can gunk up lock mechanism under extreme whether, I'm not sure I want to use it.
And then there's graphene but people say it can harden if mixed with water or moisture.
I heard manufacturers like Honda and Toyota use grease on their locks and most manufactures lube their locks during assembly.
So at this point I'm thinking that a good clean with a no residue/fast drying solvent like brake clean or electronics cleaner to wash out the existing gunk and something like dry ptfe spray or Teflon dry lubricant will do the trick.
How long before I have to clean the lock and apply the dry ptfe again though?
What do you think? Any recommendations?

Comment: Are you having problems with your locks?  If not why do you want to wash out the original lubricant?

Comment: passenger side door jammed. Think it happened during the winter time when I lived up north.

Comment: @HandyHowie do you think it's better to not clean the locks if there's no problem? Not even as preventative maintenance? 03 Ford with only manual entry.

Comment: If anyone suggests WD-40, ignore the advice. It eventually turns gummy and requires cleanout with a solvent. I knew an old locksmith, fortunately now deceased, who used WD-40 on every job, which guaranteed repeat business every few years for sticking lockworks!

Comment: Unless I was having problems with them, I think I wouldn’t mess with them.  Oil can become a magnet for dirt to build up. I don’t know what is best to do however.   There are some lock smiths on here, so maybe they will advise.

Comment: Lock-Ease has been around for decades; shake to distribute graphite in solvent, apply and solvent evaporates, leaving dry graphite as lube for lock cylinders. It will take days for solvent to dry as you'll need a napkin to wipe off lube deposits on a key. A spritz of silicone spray on the outside bezel can help dispel rain water and ice melt. I've used Lock-Ease on ski rack locks and lockable roof racks exposed to salted roads without issues.

Comment: A locksmith didn't recommend graphene for exterior use cus "the changing ambient temperatures" can make "harden the graphene" although I didn't see that in a test I saw.

Comment: I've heard good and bad things about graphene. They say it can jam exterior locks over time due to it's viscosity and attraction to water/changing temperatures. I'm breaking my head big time on this. Dunno If I should just go with the clean, lube, and grease method or just use a dry spray lube like 3 and 1 spray lube. My only concern is damaging the factory lock lubricant coat inside the lock with the solvent used to clean the lock to rid it off any contaminant, oils, old grease etc. I mean does the factory lube eventually break down and locks need re lubing?

Comment: https://youtu.be/9PKT1d1n3a0?si=wD0XHsdhg4Q8uI6r

Comment: It's a 20 year old Ford but the point is to make the locks last longer not hinder their wear cus the wrong lube was used

Comment: So with so many lubricants out there, I decided to just go with the the method of cleaning with a non-residue, fast drying lubricant like break clean and then using wd-40 specialist dry ptfe lube. From the tests and info I saw/read online, it does a pretty solid job even under extreme conditions. At least my decision is based on knowledge and research instead of just spraying wd-40 classic. We'll see what happens.